# Do not understand why the following error shows in my code: non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, swing, static

I have looked at several posts regarding the above error. However I don't understand which part of my code is incorrect.

The error applies to the following line:
tempPic.setLocation(0, slotIDArray[0]);

slotIDArray is ofcourse a non-static variable. newBloodhound, tempPic are also non-static variables. I am confused as to why there is an error related to this matter.

Context:
My code produces a GUI in which on the left side there is a panel divided into 42 "cells", each of which supports a DTPicture type (all these DTPicture cells are initialized to null. I use slotIDArray to keep an integral reference of the position i.e., pos 1 corresponds to Y= 38, etc. Just for testing purposes for later development, I assigned a random DTPicture to the Bloodhound component. Since DTPicture is a Component, I can set its location on the frame/panel. Therefore I call testPic.setLocation(0, slotIDArray[0]); to see if this picture will be transferred into the DTPicture "cell" located at that particular Y position.

Thanks for the help.

Below is the relevant segment of my code:

```
public class RackBuilderTool extends JPanel{
    public int[] slotIDArray = new int[42];

    public RackBuilderTool() {
        super(new GridLayout(42, 1));

        //DTPicture[] rackSlotArray = new DTPicture[42];
        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
                //add(new ComponentLabel());
            DTPicture temp = new DTPicture(null);
            //address of DTPicture Component
            slotIDArray[i] = add(temp).getY();


            /*
            add(new ComponentLabel("Bloodhound", "alexi.jpg", 
                    "Bloodhound label
            */
        }
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rack Builder Tool");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final RackBuilderTool rackBuilder = new RackBuilderTool();
        rackBuilder.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(rackBuilder);
        frame.pack();

        JButton bloodhoundButton = new JButton("Bloodhound");
        JButton computeButton = new JButton("Compute");
        JButton powershelfButton = new JButton("Powershelf");
        JButton serverButton = new JButton("Server");
        JButton storageButton = new JButton("Storage");
        JButton switchButton = new JButton("Switch");

        bloodhoundButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Clicked Bloodhound Button");
                //System.out.println(rackBuilder.slotRowArray[2].getLocation());
                //need to fix this. Static variable cannot be used.
                Bloodhound newBloodhound = new Bloodhound();
                DTPicture tempPic = newBloodhound.getPicture();
                tempPic.setLocation(0, slotIDArray[0]);  
            }
        });
    JToolBar rackToolBar = new JToolBar("Components", JToolBar.VERTICAL);
            rackToolBar.add(bloodhoundButton);
            rackToolBar.add(computeButton);
            rackToolBar.add(powershelfButton);
            rackToolBar.add(serverButton);
            rackToolBar.add(storageButton);
            rackToolBar.add(switchButton);
            frame.add(rackToolBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
      }
   }


    class Bloodhound extends RackComponent {
        static private int quantity = 0;
        private DTPicture compPic = new DTPicture(
                DTPicture.createImageIcon("images/alexi.jpg", "alexi").
                        getImage());

    public Bloodhound() {
            ++quantity;
        }
        public DTPicture getPicture() {
            return compPic;
        }
        public String getPartNumber() {
            return partNumber;
        }
        public int getQuantity () {
            return quantity;
        }
        public void setPartNumber(String...partNumbers) {
            this.partNumber = partNumbers[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: First off, you need to understand that an *object* is an *instance* of a class.  Methods and variables that belong to the *instance* are "non-static".  You cannot access one of those methods/variables unless you have an instance of the class to tell the JVM which instance you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slotIDArray` is a non-static variable of the class and you are trying to access it in a static method. Hence,you are getting such error.

Just make `slotIDArray` static or remove static from the definition of your method(if you can do it without any problem with your concept) to access it!

Comment: That makes sense. I did not pay attention to this static modifier for the createShowGUI() and main(). It seems I can't remove these modifiers however. I'm compiling code on Netbeans IDE and upon removing these modifiers netbeans can no longer detect main(). This concept confuses me now. Under the static createAndShowGUI() I have instantiated many objects. Why doesn't the method complain about this?

Comment: @user3761743-Don't remove static declaration from `main()`! Just while calling `createShowGUI()`,call it using an object of your class! Like new `Your_Class().createShowGUI();`
Feel free to comment if it's unclear or you don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context - this happens when you try to access the non static 
or member variable of an object. This should be obvious.

`private static void createAndShowGUI()` is a static method and you are trying to access a static variable location with
`tempPic.setLocation(0, slotIDArray[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

`newBloodhound` and `tempPic` are local variables defined within the static method. Therefore, there's no problem to access them from that method.

`slotIDArray`, on the other hand, is a non-static member of your class, and you can't access it from within a static method.